# How to convert text file into list using python:

Tags: python, list, dictionary, file-io

```
input_file=input('Plase enter your file name from the directory')

try:
    with open(input_file) as file:
        data = file.read()
except:
       print("error")
```

this is my text file data:

```
Annabel 17
Brian 9
Carlos 15
Donna 8
Edgar 19
Felipe 10
Guoning 16
Heather 12
Irene 13
```

I tried use to convert using dict as well:

```
with open("pR.txt", "rb") as file:
    dictionary = {}
    for line in file:
        k,v = line.strip().split("=")
        dictionary[k.strip] = v.strip()
    print(dictionary)
```

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: `not working` - what is wrong? How is it *not working*?

Comment: The first example never prints anything, so how do you know it's not working?  The second example splits on `=`, which is not present in the file.

Comment: Why are you splitting on = if your text file as spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```py
try:
    with open("test.txt") as f:
        file = f.readlines()
except:
    print("error")

data = {}
for line in file:
    name, id = line.split()
    data[name] = id
```

Notice the [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) as opposed to `read()`. The above will set the `data` dict to the following:

```
{'Annabel': '17', 'Brian': '9', 'Carlos': '15', 'Donna': '8', 'Edgar': '19', 'Felipe': '10', 'Guoning': '16', 'Heather': '12', 'Irene': '13'}
```

Here is a three line solution as well, using unpacking and dict comprehension.

```py
with open("test.txt") as f:
    file = f.readlines()
    data = {name: id for line in file for name, id in [line.split()]}
```